# Xcode cannot find .dylib alias, even though it's there

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, dylib

I want to create an iOS app that uses the [LabStreamingLayer library](https://github.com/sccn/liblsl) (LSL). This library is a C++ library with no official release for iOS, but it uses CMake for building, so I used [this toolchain file](https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake) to create an iOS release build myself.

The resulting files of the build are:

- .bcsymbolmap files
- liblsl.1.15.2.dylib (the actual .dylib)
- liblsl.2.dylib (an alias to the actual .dylib)
- liblsl.dylib (also an alias)
- lslver (a CLI app)

I have also used the toolchain to install the library on my Mac (even though it's a build for iOS, it's globally available in `/usr/local/lib/` for Xcode - more on that later).

I have copied the .dylib files (including the aliases) and the headers used in the LSL library into separate folders on my Desktop to use them exclusively for this project.

So, on to the Xcode project setup:

- The app is written in SwiftUI.
- I wrote an Objective-C wrapper for LSL that calls the C methods of LSL (the C++ methods were somehow not directly compatible with Objective-C, not sure about the exact reason anymore). I added a [sample method from the examples](https://github.com/sccn/liblsl/blob/master/examples/ReceiveDataC.c) included in the library repository in the wrapper. To link the wrapper to the rest of the project, I added a bridging header as well.
- I add a button in the `ContentView` that calls the method in the wrapper.

Now, onto the build settings:

- I added the library in the **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** section of the General tab of the target settings. I selected the .dylib file I had copied into the desktop folder I mentioned above and embedded and signed it. [See screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HvXr.png)
- I added to the Framework Search Paths and Header Search Paths the same desktop folder with the libraries inside.
- I added to the Library Search Paths in the Build Settings the desktop folder with the headers I also mentioned above.
- I added `$(inherited)` and `@executable_path/Frameworks` to the Runpath Search Paths.
- The Build Phases look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFPNe.png).

The problem is, when I run, the app crashes directly after starting with a `SIGABRT` and the stack trace pointing at `` dyld`__abort_with_payload ``.
The debug output looks like this:

```
dyld[5432]: Library not loaded: @rpath/liblsl.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/LSL Library Test 15.0
  Reason: tried: 
    '/usr/lib/system/introspection/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/usr/local/lib/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/usr/lib/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file)

Library not loaded: @rpath/liblsl.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/LSL Library Test 15.0
  Reason: tried: 
    '/usr/lib/system/introspection/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-identifier>/LSL Library Test 15.0.app/Frameworks/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/usr/local/lib/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/usr/lib/liblsl.2.dylib' (no such file)
```

For some reason, Xcode additionally looks for the alias of the library, too - I am not sure why since I do not know how the library exactly works. However, I am surprised that it cannot find it since all the search paths are configured correctly. All the .dylib files (included in the aliases) are available in the desktop folder and in `/usr/local/lib/` folder too (that's why I installed the library using the toolchain and added `/usr/local/lib/` to the library and framework search paths).

What is the solution for this?

**EDIT:** Running `otool -l /usr/local/lib/liblsl.dylib | fgrep -A2 LC_ID_DYLIB` outputs:

```
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name @rpath/liblsl.2.dylib (offset 24)
```

**EDIT:** Directly adding the `liblsl.2.dylib` alias in the Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content section still symlinks directly to the original `liblsl.1.15.2.dylib`.

Comment: Looks like your lib isn't correctly deployed.

Comment: The fact that it's looking for `liblsl.2.dylib` makes me think that that is the true embedded name of the dylib. Could you add the output of `otool -l /usr/local/lib/liblsl.dylib | fgrep -A2 LC_ID_DYLIB` to your question? And if that says `liblsl.2.dylib` rather than `liblsl.1.15.2.dylib`, could you try adding the `liblsl.2.dylib` symlink to that "embed & sign" instead of the actual dylib? I think this is a simple file naming issue.

Comment: Ok I somehow came up with a solution  Thanks for your help and for your time though!

Comment: @krstndm Please post an answer detailing how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: The solution is so trivial that it really baffled me. I just renamed the `lib.1.15.2.dylib` file to `lib.2.dylib` (basically the filename Xcode is looking for), imported it and it worked. Yes.